# Installation of keras fails with Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

Software Information:

**SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 5**

Symbolic link

**/usr/bin/python3 --version** returns the below;
**Python 3.4.10**

**R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"**

I run the below commands to install keras in the R console.

> install.packages("reticulate")

> install.packages("tensorflow")

> install.packages("tfruns")

> install.packages("magrittr")

> install.packages("zeallot")

> install.packages("R6")

> install.packages("generics")

> packageurl<-"https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/keras/keras_2.2.4.tar.gz"

> install.packages(packageurl,repos=NULL,type="source")

> library(keras)

> install_keras(tensorflow = "1.9")

In the last step, I get the below error.

**Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3**

Any help is appreciated here.

Thanks in advance,
Venkatesh

Comment: Hello! I have the same issue, with install_tensorflow(), did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: I also have the same problem! I've updated pip, numpy, virtualenv. I've installed anaconda to attempt install_tensorflow(method="conda") but still no luck. I hate that rstudio has put it all this effort to make the installation just work :/ it seems like i will have to manually install :/

Answer (score 0):

I am using an Arch Linux system with R (version 4.1.1). Assuming you have installed [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux-aarch64/) in your system and is recognized in your path, after you have already installed the `reticulate` package:

1. Load the `reticulate` package: `library(reticulate)`
2. Specify the alternate python version to be used: `use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")`
3. Specify the environment: `use_virtualenv("myenv")`
4. Now install tensorflow:`install.packages('tensorflow')` then finally `install_tensorflow(method = 'conda', envname = 'r-reticulate')`

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.4 is not supported by tensorflow, you need minimum 3.6.
Additionally, R/reticulate will avoid making changes to a system python installation (anything under `/usr/` or `/usr/local`).

In R, the reticulate package can configure the python environment for you if that makes things easier:

```
install.packages("keras")

# this will configure a python environment for R 
reticulate::install_miniconda() 

# this will install into the environment configured by reticulate
keras::install_keras()
```